# Unable to install sonarqube 7.1 on windows

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am facing an issue while trying to install SonarQube.

Here is the log:

```
E:\sonarqube-7.1 (1)\sonarqube-7.1\bin\windows-x86-64>startsonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory E:\sonarqube-7.1 (1)\sonarqube-7.1\temp
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [E:\sonarqube-7.1 (1)\sonarqube-7.1\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=E:\sonarqube-7.1 (1)\sonarqube-7.1\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=E:\sonarqube-7.1 (1)\sonarqube-7.1\temp\conf\es
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
jvm 1    | Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
jvm 1    | Must use the serial GC in the DCEVM
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2018.05.21 13:20:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
jvm 1    | FATAL StatusLogger Interrupted before Log4j Providers could be loaded.
jvm 1    |  java.lang.InterruptedException
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1220)
jvm 1    |      at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:335)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:121)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:108)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:89)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:54)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:105)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Loggers.java:72)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractComponent.<init>(AbstractComponent.java:37)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:97)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:101)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:126)
jvm 1    |      at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:254)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor$MinimalTransportClient.<init>(EsProcessMonitor.java:109)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.buildTransportClient(EsProcessMonitor.java:175)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.getTransportClient(EsProcessMonitor.java:160)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.checkStatus(EsProcessMonitor.java:134)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.checkOperational(EsProcessMonitor.java:93)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.isOperational(EsProcessMonitor.java:78)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess.refreshState(SQProcess.java:161)
jvm 1    |      at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess$EventWatcher.run(SQProcess.java:220)
jvm 1    | ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Which JDK did you used ? Could you try with Oracle one ?

Comment: Thanks,

I changed JDK version , issue got fixed.

Comment: Great thanks for the follow up !

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I had JDK 1.8 installed, reverting it to JDK 11 fixed the issue.